# Detach a --pty interactive Slurm job, so it can be reattached after a reboot

Tags: slurm, detach, interactive-shell

I wish to detach a `srun --pty ...` Slurm job, so that when I close the terminal I used to connect to the SSH session, and shutdown my PC, I can still reconnect later using `sattach --pty JOBID`.

How can I detach without killing the job?

Thanks in advance.